Snowflake - DAG with multiple tasks roots
I have multiple tasks roots that loads data in different final tables. Now i need to create another final table that loads the table of those previous final tables on this one.
And the thing is that i need to wait for all this (4 final tables) that are loaded with a new process date data to execute this final task and the procedure inside.
I'm creating this last task with the condition of all the previous tasks are finished but its alleging that this final task doesn't have an unique root task.
How could i proceed? I need to validate if all the previous tasks that loads this 4 final tables are loaded before i execute this final one.
Thanks
Edit: Ended up creating a new root task that is triggered when one or more of the previous root tasks streams has data.
After this, all second level tasks are triggered simultaneously and only the one that uses the stream that has data continuous his process.

This question needs focus but try exploring Dynamic Tables, looks like this use case could use them

A DAG has to have a single parent task. If you can’t link your 4 initial tasks to a single parent task then you’ll have to re-think your design

Can you share your current setup and desired goal? More specifics will help us propose a solution around your needs

@NickW, yeah men that what i was suspecting, i ended up creating a root task that is triggered when all of the streams that before where the main condition of each of the previous root tasks, if one of those have data, this new root task is triggered with a system$wait function. Then all of the second level tasks are triggered simultaneously and only the one that uses the stream that has data continuos his process. Isn't the nicest solution but is what i ended up doing. Thanks
